# Outlook calendar invite for second last Monday of the month

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, appointments

Is there a way to create a recurring invite on Outlook calendar for the second last Monday of the month.
I understand how to create it for the last Monday of the month, but what if I want the second last? Obviously with some months having 4 weeks and some 5 weeks, I cannot use the third or fourth function in the appointment recurrence window.

Appointment recurrence pop up window:
[image: appointment recurrence pop up window]

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found (because there is no way to mechanize what you want) is as follows:

Make an appointment in the first period you want and save it.

Now go to that appointment and copy it (Control - C).

Then move to the next period (no appointment) and Paste it (Paste or Control - V).

You can usually move through a series of periods this way.

I have done this for customers when my usual day is a Monday but there is a Holiday Monday. I copy and then paste into Tuesday.

This works very well and fast enough that no time is wasted.

Since you cannot mechanize it is the next best thing.